# Replacing @timestamp using datetime from JDBC input

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

How does someone replace `@timestamp` field in a Logstash pipeline without converting DateTime to a string and then doing a date filter on that column?

```ruby
mutate {
  convert => ["datetime", "string"]
}
date {
  match => ["datetime", "ISO8601"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple filters, it's possible to perform a simple rename to a field, doing it as follows:

```ruby
mutate {
  id => "sample-rename-timestamp"
  rename => {
    "datetime" => "@timestamp"
  }
}
```

This will replace message arrival `@timestamp` with your provided field.

Answer (score 1):

Because the jdbc output field *datetime* is a date type, so we can copy it as @timestamp field.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "datetime" => "@timestamp" }
 }
}
```